# How to update screen in this on button push?

Tags: python, function, pygame, display

I got this little program in Pygame. It runs a time which does actions every 2 seconds. What exactly it is doing in these 2 seconds I left out in my code.
Now, I am able to push Enter while the program is running and count the time Enter has been pushed.
My only issue is, that the font won't update, even if i use pygame.display.update(). It always displays the numbers on the same place on screen. Can someone help me please?

```py
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False

font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 72)


start = time.time()
i=0
F = 0;

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:

                F = F + 1

                text4 = font.render(str(F), True, (128, 128, 0))

                screen.blit(text4,
                            (460 - text4.get_width() // 1, 40 + i * 20 - text4.get_height() // 2))
                pygame.display.update()
                clock.tick(30)


    passed_time = time.time() - start

    clock.tick(30)

    if passed_time > 2 and i < 5:  
        start = time.time()  
        i = i + 1
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(text4,
                (320 - text4.get_width() // 2, 240 - text4.get_height() // 2))

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text which is drawn in the event loop is draw one single time when the event occurs, but it is immediately covered by `screen.fill((255, 255, 255))`. Everything what is drawn in the main loop is drawn continuously in every frame.

Don't do any extra `pygame.display.flip()` or `pygame.display.update()` beside that in the main loop. Add a condition a draw the text dependent on the condition in the main loop.
e.g. The condition can be `text4 != None`:

```py
text4 = None
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            done = True

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                F = F + 1
                text4 = font.render(str(F), True, (128, 128, 0))

    passed_time = time.time() - start
    if passed_time > 2 and i < 5:  
        start = time.time()  
        i += 1

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

    if text4 != None:
        screen.blit(text4,(460 - text4.get_width() // 1, 40 + i * 20 - text4.get_height() // 2))

    # [...]

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Remove all `pygame.display.flip()` and `clock.tick()` from the code, except that at the end of the main loop. But use conditions and functions for selectively drawing the scene.

Comment: Thanks so much! What is the meaning of  text4!=None? The code does not really work. Is there a mistake?

Comment: @DerickKolln` text4` is initialized by `None` (first line of the code). I the event `text4` is set  `text4 = font.render(...)`. So `text4 != None` evaluates if `text4` is not `None` and was set in the event.

Comment: @DerickKolln Waht do you mean by  *"The code does not really work."* What does not work? It works fine, I've tested it right now.

Comment: I think i just copy and pasted it wrong. What part follows the  `if text4 != None` condition? There, where you placed the dots?

Comment: @DerickKolln For an working example nothing has to be there. Its the place for the rest of your calculations, for "your" code. Note, there is a variable `text` in your code, which is not defined.

Comment: I wanted to ask you where to put my condition `if passed_time > 2 and i < 5:`? I also just edited the undefined `text` variable. Can i ask you a question in german in the chat section?

Comment: @DerickKolln I've added the code to the answer. The code which draws `text` has to be put at `# [...]`

Comment: Thanks so much! Can I ask one more question? It just left the `clock.tick()` parts in the conditions by accident. But it seems like it makes no diffenrence. Is there an explanation?

Comment: @DerickKolln The best explanation of [`pygame.time.Clock.tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) is the documentation: *"This method should be called once per frame. It will compute how many milliseconds have passed since the previous call.

If you pass the optional framerate argument the function will delay to keep the game running slower than the given ticks per second. This can be used to help limit the runtime speed of a game. By calling Clock.tick(40) once per frame, the program will never run at more than 40 frames per second."*

Comment: Can i ask you a last question? If I wanna display an additional static font. That means i have a dynamic font and a static font. DoI need to put `pygame.display.update()` back into the condition of the static font to make that happen? Or is it better to place `screen.blit()` into the static condition?